# Get the selected item of a ListView

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

how can I get the selected item (the object) from a ListView in WinRT?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: for c# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031465/getting-selected-item-information-from-listview-in-winrt

Comment: for xaml see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551766/xaml-listview-change-image-source-for-selected-item

Comment: vb http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?165593-How-to-select-item-in-a-listView-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem) property. You can use binding:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

Or you can access the property from code behind:

```
var item = myListView.SelectedItem;
```

If your [`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selectionmode) isn't `Single` use [`SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selecteditems) instead.